# Python requests failing but Postman return 200

Tags: python

My requests API call works, as in it returns a 200, but it fails to load the JSON object.

```
import requests

xvg_wallet = 'http://api.yiimp.eu/api/wallet?address=DLGuHUwkycBFFajtbMJwMqvcgZ6cVDebCY'
w = requests.get(xvg_wallet).json()
print(w)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brett\Downloads\verge.py", line 4, in <module>
    w = requests.get(xvg_wallet).json()
  File "C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 826, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

However, the same GET with the Postman application returns nothing but success.

[image]

What am I doing wrong with Python?

Comment: Your Postman screenshot shows the request has 7 headers. Did you add them to your Python code?

Comment: as of his code he posted he didn't included any headers

Comment: can print and paste output of `requests.get(xvg_wallet)` without json()

Comment: Is that OK to show us your wallet address?

Comment: without .json() I get <Response [200]>
and yes, it's fine to show the wallet address as its the receive address, feel free to send me verge :)

Comment: The screenshot shows there are 7 headers inside the *response* but not request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include headers when you request see the code below:

```
import requests

xvg_wallet = 'http://api.yiimp.eu/api/walletaddress=DLGuHUwkycBFFajtbMJwMqvcgZ6cVDebCY'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
w = requests.get(xvg_wallet, headers=headers).json()
print(w)
```

Output:

```
{'balance': 0.0,
 'currency': 'XVG',
 'paid24h': 65.10781097,
 'total': 68.29277167,
 'unpaid': 3.1849607,
 'unsold': 3.1849607040682}
```

Comment: You're right, thanks for the heads up. I've never had to manually declare headers before. Good to know :)